# Does default directory structure for .net Blazor have to stay?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am very new to working with C# and the blazor. (I do have experience working with Svelte, react and other frameworks. But none with C#.

I was curious if/how I can create my own folder structure from the templated structure it gives when you run `dotnet new blazorwasm`.

```
.vscode/
bin/
obj/
Pages/
Properties/
Shared/
wwwroot/
_Imports.razor
Program.cs
Program.csproj
Project.sln
```

Following the tutorials microsoft has, they just put scripts into the root folder, which I do not like.

Any advice would be appreciated thanks!

EDIT:
@andrew wynn
Okay I understand. But outside of the `wwwroot` folder, can I take and move folders into other folders like `Pages` or `Shared` which contain razor component files? Something like this? Because from what I can tell I don't see anything linking them directly. It looks like everything is linked via namespaces if I am understanding it correctly.

```
.vscode/
bin/
obj/
Pages/
Properties/
Shared/
wwwroot/
_Imports.razor
Program.cs
Program.csproj
Project.sln
```

Answer (score 1):

`wwwroot` is the root directory for the site, so it's where all of the source files go. They can go into subdirectories in there as long as they are referetially linked.

You can make some middleware to use a different folder if you wish though, see [this link][1]

Edit:

So each of the folders in a Blazor project is for a specific set of files. `Pages` is there for the .blazor and .cshtml files, these don't exist on the public facing site as they are dynamically translated into html when requested.

I'm not entirely sure what it is you would like to acheive. The folder structure is hard coded into the server host application. The static components (javascript, css, html, images etc) all go into `wwwroot` as they can be accessed directly by clients, the content to dynamically generate by ASP.NET or Blazor is in `Pages`, your classes and such go in `Data`... Do you just want to rename these folders?
.
[1]: [JS File outside www root folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43653305/js-file-outside-www-root-folder)

Comment: I edited to my question, if you could take a look- it responds to your comment. Thanks!

Comment: Not rename them no, but I would like to create a “src” folder or something along that line, and put Pages and the Shared folders inside of it, as well as any other files/folders I’d create. As soon as I get a chance I will post an example! Thank you for your explanations so far though!

Comment: Something like [this structure](https://tree.nathanfriend.io/?s=(%27options!(%27fancy6~fullPath!false~trailingSlash6~CotDot6)~s7!(%27s7!%27.vscode-bin-obj-S7*PagesBIndex3*SharedBMainLayout3BNavMenu3*4sB418B428*DataBDatabaseAccess89perties-wwwCot-_imports3-App355pCj9ject.sln%27)~version!%271%27)*-0-%5Cn0%20%203.razor4Script59gram86!true7ource8.cs9-PCB*0Cro%01CB98765430-*).

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out. Yes you can structure it how ever you want. You just to make sure you update the `_imports.razor` file to reference the new location.

So if I move everything into a Source folder I would need to update.

```
@using MyProject.Shared

//TO
@using MyProject.Source.Shared
```

And then make sure to add any new files that need referenced.

Comment: You don't need to add global usings in this way.  You can add a using to any file that needs it.  I recommend only adding re-usable components to  your usings

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can move folders. It is best to show with an example. If we want to move `Pages`, `Shared` and `wwwroot` to be subfolders, like this:

```
View/
  Pages
  Shared
  wwwroot
```

Then in `program.cs` you have the following modifications:

```c#
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions {
    WebRootPath = Path.Combine("View", "wwwroot")
});
```

```c#
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options => { options.RootDirectory = "/View/Pages"; });
```

And in `_Imports.razor`

```c#
@using YourAppName.View
@using YourAppName.View.Pages
@using YourAppName.View.Shared
```